# geth keeps opening & re-opening in background (OSX 10.10.5)

Tags: go-ethereum, installation, mac-osx

Issue started after installing cpp-ethereum & updating geth to 1.3.3. Geth continually re-opens in the background after being forced to shut down. When I try and run geth in terminal, I receive the following error:

> Fatal: Error starting Ethereum: listen udp :30303: bind: address already >in use (possibly another instance of geth is using the same port)

Tried a hard re-start, after which geth re-opened in the background again. Tried uninstalling cpp-ethereum and uninstalling geth (both 1.3.3 and the previous 1.2.2). As soon as it is reinstalled, geth opens up in the background.

Open to any and all suggestions!

Comment: How are you installing Geth?

Comment: using brew, e.g. ----


'==> Installing ethereum from ethereum/ethereum
==> Downloading https://build.ethdev.com/builds/bottles/ethereum-1.3.3.yosemite.
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/ethereum-1.3.3.yosemite.bottle.8.tar.gz
==> Pouring ethereum-1.3.3.yosemite.bottle.8.tar.gz
==> Caveats
To reload ethereum/ethereum/ethereum after an upgrade:
  launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.ethereum.plist
  launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.ethereum.plist
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/ethereum/1.3.3: 18 files, 87.0M'

Comment: `launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.ethereum.plist` should hopefully prevent geth from booting on restart. Could you try that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you install geth via the brew package it sets up an automatic launch script so Geth launches during boot.

If this is not desirable you can disable it using:

```
launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.ethereum.plist
```

If this does not do the trick, then open the homebrew.mxcl.ethereum.plist file (for example in Xcode) and change the Boolean values of RunAtLoad and KeepAlive from 'true' to 'false'.